# How to find common prime factors of two given numbers in C?

Tags: c, math, primes

I am trying to solve this problem:

Input: the first line contains an integer `T` which represents the total cases you need to solve. Each test case contains `P` and `Q`, separated by space, represent the number you need to work on.

Output: print the result which is calculated from the multiplication of `P` and `Q`’s minimum factor and maximum prime factor.

Constraints: **1 ≤  ≤ 100** and **2 ≤ , ≤ 1000000**

Sample Input: `2 210 84 6 12`
Sample Output:

```
Case #1: 14 
Case #2: 6
```

Explanation: Let’s take an example from the first case. The numbers 210 and 84 have several identical prime factors which are 2, 3, and 7. Number ‘2’ is the smallest common prime factor of the numbers, meanwhile number ‘7’ is their largest common prime factor. So, the result must be the multiplication of 2 and 7, which is 14.

Here's my code that I've been working, I tried to find factors from the given number the store the factors into array then check for the prime, but I feel that this isn't the right algorithm :(

```
void factor(int num1) {
    int arrA[100000], a = 0, flag = 1;
    //check factor
    for (int i = 2; i <= num1; i++) {
        if (num1 % i == 0) {
            arrA[a] = i;
            a++;
        }
    }
    // check prime
    for (int i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        for (int j = 2; j < a; j++) {
            if ((arrA[i] % j) == 0) {
                flag = 0;
            }
        }
        if (flag == 1) {
            printf("%d ", arrA[i]);
        }
        flag = 1;
    }
    printf("\n");
}
```

Comment: Is this an attempt at prime factorization?

Comment: `int arrA[100000]` is already on the edge of a disaster.  Move this off the stack.

Comment: You probably also want to divide your value by the prime and re-run your factorization to catch all factors.  Also, no need to check all primes - you can stop when arrA[i] squared is bigger than your factor.

Comment: Replace the `j < a` with `j < arrA[i]`. But your algorithm is very inefficient.

Comment: @MichaelDorgan i want to find the all of the primes from a given number, ex : if I input 14 the output should be 2 and 7, if I input 18 the output should be 2 and 3 but I can't figure it out

Comment: @M.NejatAydin sorry mate, im still new to this

Comment: @500-InternalServerError it is, but i want to find all the primes from a given number, ex : if I input 14 the output should be 2 and 7, if i input 12 the output should be 2 and 3

Comment: I think you should find an array of prime numbers up to 1000000 first, then use it for finding the least and the biggest prime factor of any input. BTW, what if an input is a prime? Does it count twice,  both as a minimum and as a maximum prime factor of itself?

Comment: Just a suggestion:  Although cute, the entire first paragraph is completely irrelevant.  You should really consider replacing it with something similar to what it said before.  Keep the text relevant to the problem being presented.

Comment: @ryyker well, sorry for that

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your function does not compute the prime factors correctly because it will find factors that are not prime. For `num = 6`, it will find `2`, `3` but also `6`.

You should divide `num` by `i` when you find that `i` divides `num` and otherwise increase `i`.

You can then make `arrA` much smaller as the maximum number of prime factors in an `int` is less than the number of bits in an `int`: `31` would suffice for 32-bit ints and `63` for 64-bit ints.

Once you have the prime factors of `num`, you should try and find the smallest and largest that divide the other number. Note that the first and last such prime numbers could be identical or might not even exist if the numbers have no common prime factor.

Note that you do not need to store the factors: for every prime factor of `num`, you can try and check if it divides the other number and keep the first one that does and the last one too.

Here is a simple implementation:

```c
#include <stdio.h>

int main() {
    int i, n, a, aa, b, p, p1, p2;

    if (scanf("%d", &n) == 1) {
        for (i = 1; i <= n; i++) {
            if (scanf("%d%d", &a, &b) != 2)
                break;
            p1 = p2 = 1;
            aa = a;
            for (p = 2; p * p <= aa; p++) {
                if (aa % p == 0) {
                    /* p is a prime factor of a */
                    if (b % p == 0) {
                        /* p is a common prime factor */
                        p2 = p;
                        if (p1 == 1) {
                            /* p is the smallest common prime factor */
                            p1 = p;
                        }
                    }
                    /* remove p as a factor of aa */
                    do { aa /= p; } while (aa % p == 0);
                }
            }
            if (aa > 1) {
                /* aa is the largest prime factor of a */
                if (b % aa == 0) {
                    /* aa is the largest common prime factor */
                    p2 = aa;
                    if (p1 == 1) {
                        /* aa is also the smallest common prime factor */
                        p1 = aa;
                    }
                }
            }
            /* print the product of the smallest and largest common prime factors */
            /* if a == b and a is a large prime, a * a might overflow int */
            printf("Case #%d: %lld\n", i, (long long)p1 * p2);
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: what's this for?
if (a > 1) {
            if (b % a == 0) {
                /* a is the largest prime factor */
                if (p1 == 1)
                    p1 = a;
                    p2 = a;
                }
        }

Comment: @selowboi: at the end of the factorisation loop, the final value of `a` is the largest prime factor or `1` if the largest factor has already been found with a power greater than 1. This test handles this factor if it also divides `b`. I updated the code with explanatory comments and a better factorisation loop.